# Can you count the number of self-loops per vertex in a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In this graph, such output would be: 0 self-loops for vertex `w`, 1 self-loop for vertex `c`, 6 self-loops for vertex `r`, etc.

The adjacency matrix is from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/361073909_Decryption_and_Topology_of_the_Genetic_Code):

```
m1 = {
   w <-> x, x <-> c, c <-> c,
   x <-> x, x <-> y, y <-> y,
   s <-> s, s <-> s, s <-> s,
   l <-> l, l <-> f, f <-> f,
   
   r <-> r, r <-> r, r <-> r,
   q <-> q, q <-> h, h <-> h,
   p <-> p, p <-> p, p <-> p,
   l <-> l, l <-> l, l <-> l,
   
   r <-> r, r <-> s, s <-> s,
   k <-> k, k <-> n, n <-> n,
   t <-> t, t <-> t, t <-> t,
   m <-> i, i <-> i, i <-> i,
   
   g <-> g, g <-> g, g <-> g,
   e <-> e, e <-> d, d <-> d,
   a <-> a, a <-> a, a <-> a,
   v <-> v, v <-> v, v <-> v,
   
   
   
   w <-> x, x <-> s, s <-> l,
   x <-> x, x <-> s, s <-> l,
   c <-> y, y <-> s, s <-> f,
   c <-> y, y <-> s, s <-> f,
   
   r <-> q, q <-> p, p <-> l,
   r <-> q, q <-> p, p <-> l,
   r <-> h, h <-> p, p <-> l,
   r <-> h, h <-> p, p <-> l,
   
   r <-> k, k <-> t, t <-> m,
   r <-> k, k <-> t, t <-> i,
   s <-> n, n <-> t, t <-> i,
   s <-> n, n <-> t, t <-> i,
   
   g <-> e, e <-> a, a <-> v,
   g <-> e, e <-> a, a <-> v,
   g <-> d, d <-> a, a <-> v,
   g <-> d, d <-> a, a <-> v,
   
   
   
   w <-> r, r <-> r, r <-> g,
   x <-> r, r <-> r, r <-> g,
   c <-> r, r <-> s, s <-> g,
   c <-> r, r <-> s, s <-> g,
   
   x <-> k, k <-> k, k <-> e,
   x <-> k, k <-> k, k <-> e,
   y <-> h, h <-> n, n <-> d,
   y <-> h, h <-> n, n <-> d,
   
   s <-> p, p <-> t, t <-> a,
   s <-> p, p <-> t, t <-> a,
   s <-> p, p <-> t, t <-> a,
   s <-> p, p <-> t, t <-> a,
   
   l <-> l, l <-> m, m <-> v,
   l <-> l, l <-> i, i <-> v,
   f <-> l, l <-> i, i <-> v,
   f <-> l, l <-> i, i <-> v
   };
Graph[m1, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image: Graph:]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to comment yesterday. I found it quite difficult to understand what the question was, so I edited the text for clarity. Hope that's fine with you.

Answer (score 7):

```
G= Graph[m1];
AssociationThread[
 VertexList[G],
 Normal[Diagonal[AdjacencyMatrix[G]]]
 ]
```

> <|w -> 0, x -> 2, c -> 1, y -> 1, s -> 4, l -> 6, f -> 1, r -> 6,
> q -> 1, h -> 1, p -> 3, k -> 3, n -> 1, t -> 3, m -> 0, i -> 2,
> g -> 3, e -> 1, d -> 1, a -> 3, v -> 3|>

Comment: Presumably `G = Graph[m1]`? ;)

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!